# Why cBot (cTrader) is not respecting my stop loss?

Tags: c#

I have the following code that executes orders for cBot (cTrader) after calculating the maximum amount of risk the position can take. The (hidden) code does calculate the value properly but somehow cTrader is opening the position with another SL (much higher than what was calculated and executed).

```
if (condition)
{
    ExecuteMarketOrder(TradeType.Buy, _symbol.Name, _symbol.QuantityToVolumeInUnits(PositionQuantity), positionLabel, stopLossPriceBuy, null);
}
else if (condition2)
{
    ExecuteMarketOrder(TradeType.Sell, _symbol.Name, _symbol.QuantityToVolumeInUnits(PositionQuantity), positionLabel, stopLossPriceSell, null);
}
```

The log:

[image]

Note: the calculated SL is correct and set on the execution but the position has another value, as shows on the screenshot from the log above. The issue is that cTrader is ignoring the SL it was previously set and it's replacing by another one itself. I've tried different ways of fixing this but no luck so far.

The position:

[image]

I highlighted with yellow the SL it was set on the execution of the position and the SL the position actually has. See there was no modification of the order after that (that could have changed the SL).

Is it a bug or what? Can anyone see what's the issue there? Thank you!

Comment: This seems like it would be better asked [on cTrader's forums](https://ctrader.com/forum/) than here. Here, we'd need to know a lot more information than a couple of screenshots and a few lines of code.

Comment: Hey, thanks for you answer, I do understand it'd need to see the full code but I'd like to avoid posting it here. Could you see a reason why that happens? The only thing I can think of is that another part of the code could have changing the SL but how's possible that the execution has a SL value and the opened position has another one, without having any modification done? If I have at least an idea why that happens I could try to fix but that does'nt make sense to me. I've asked the cTrader support team too.

Comment: I don't know anything about cTrader. That was kind of the point :). I don't see how anyone could diagnose anything from the little bits of information provided, and if you're not going to post it, then this is unlikely a good place for the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ExecuteMarketOrder() get pips as stop loss but you pass an absolute price. You need to convert your stop loss to relative pips from the position's entry price